# how to access elements from jobjectarray in jni

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a java method which is called from my native method and returns an object array to the native code.

The elements of the object array are set as,

```
  Object[] arr = new Object[10];
    arr[0] = new Integer(12);
    arr[1] = new Float(25.5f);
```

I receive this array in my native code as follows,

```
  jobjectArray a = (jobjectArray)(*env)->CallStaticObjectMethodA(env, <class_id>, <method_id>, <parameter_list>);
```

I have the datatype of each of the element stored in object array. So based on the datatype how can I access the corresponding integer and float value in my native method.

I tried the following,

```
 jobject obj = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, a, 0);
    int num = (jint)obj;
```

But the value, that is set to num is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does auto-unboxing when you convert an `Integer` to an `int`. But that mechanic doesn't exist in C. What you're doing is taking the memory address of the element and interpreting it as an `int`.

If you want to get an `int` from an `Integer` on the `C` side, you will have to call `intValue`:

```
jobject objInteger = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, a, 0);    

jclass cInteger = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID intValue = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cInteger, "intValue", "()I");
int i = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objInteger, intValue);
```